# Cannot connect to mongod running in Ubuntu machine

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, meteor, mongovue

I would like to connect with mongo from a cmd shell in windows to a mongod database running in a Ubuntu virtual machine.

mongo is running fine in the Ubuntu terminal and from a putty shell
When I use mongo from a windows cmd shell, I got this error:

> mongo.exe --host 192.168.1.6 --port 27017
>   MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6
>   connecting to: 192.168.1.6:27017/test
>   Sat Feb 01 14:45:32.181 Error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.1.6:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
>   exception: connect failed

What should I do to be able to connect?

My goal is to use MongoVue to connect to the mongod database in the Ubuntu machine (by the way, MongoVue is not connecting even using its SSH options).

I am trying to connect to the mongod instance of a meteorjs application.
The meteor application is up and running and I can connect to the mongod instance running on the Ubuntu machine at port 3002, both in the Ubuntu terminal and with a putty shell.

```
stefano@MeteorDeploy:~$ mongo --port 3002
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3002/test
PRIMARY> show dbs
local   0.0625GB
meteor  0.0625GB
```

I would like to connect to the mongod instance using MongoVue as alternative of the putty shell.
I did as in the docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/ but without success.

Comment: Are the firewall ports open for MongoDb? 27017.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor runs it's own instance of mongo per app. As you note since your edit, when you ssh into your VM you use --port 3002 to connect.

Now you could add that port to your mongo shell launch except for one problem

ps -ef | grep mongo

on your VM will show you the running instance of mongo along with it's startup options. By default this will be bound to `127.0.0.1` which is the loopback adaptor and not accessible outside of the VM.

So what you need to do is either change the startup options in your project, or use another instance on mongo installed on the local machine.

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/your_db
```

Comment: If someone needs, these are the steps:
1) add in \etc\mongodb.conf to the 'bind_ip' option the connecting pc ip address
2) start a mongod instance with your dbpath and add your db, i.e. 'mydb'
3) run 'export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb'
4) run 'meteor' and it will use 'mydb'
5) connect with MongoVue at ubuntu ip at port 27017

Answer (score 0):

By default mongod insllation on Ubuntu only listen to localhost, so you can't connect from Windows.

Edit /etc/mongodb.conf and change the bind_ip line (add your windows IP adress on the local network) so it will accept connection.

Be aware that by default mongod does not require authentification so you would maybe want to settup one.

Doc is here :
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#bind_ip

Comment: Great! It works adding to bind_ip the address of the Windows pc. I can see from mongo running on Windows a mongod server running on ubuntu at port 27017. However I am not still able to see the mongod ubuntu server instance started with the meteorjs app at port 3002. How should I modify the mongodb.conf?

Answer (score 0):

For quick and dirty solution (not for Production):

Edit /etc/mongodb.conf and change the bind_ip to 0.0.0.0